# If Statement Not Working When Including Cells That Have Formulas

Tags: excel, formulas

*=if(a1>10,1,0)*

The problem that I'm having is that cell A1 has a formula that generates a percentage...

So, the formula above isn't giving the correct answer...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell with the information you provide.  Perhaps you misunderstand that `10%` is not the same as `10`?  Perhaps you are not referencing the cell correctly? Perhaps you have a typo? For better assistance, suggest you read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then edit your question to provide more clarity.

Comment: Do you mean `=IF(A1>.1,1,0)`? What do you mean?  What's the "correct" answer; what does the input look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try =IF(VALUE(A1)>10;1;0)

Comment: Thanks for all your input... 1) Ron, you're right - I needed to include a percentage sign inside the formula; 2) And I also took Oalvinegros suggestion: =IF(value(A1)>10%,1,0)... That worked.